# How to R present two colsums with ggplot stat_summary?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think R designed tool for the taks is `ggplot2 stat_summary` so I rejected `barplot` because of the linked thread in the body.

The problem here is the declaration of R table structure with column headers `ECG 1` and `ECG 2` for the sums `M.1.sum` and `M.2.sum`, respectively, I think. 
I try to do it with `means.long <- melt(M.1.sum, M.2.sum)`. 
Each item, `M.1.sum` and `M.2.sum`, has corresponding row-wise ids in `ids` which should also included in the data structure itself, I think. 
My proposal for its table column and row declarations is with `aes(x=ids, y=value)` where `value` is about the sums in `ggplot` declaration. 
Code

```
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')

M <- structure(c(-0.21, -0.205, -0.225, -0.49, -0.485, -0.49, 
   -0.295, -0.295, -0.295, -0.56, -0.575, -0.56, -0.69, -0.67, 
   -0.67, -0.08, -0.095, -0.095), .Dim = c(3L, 6L))
M2 <- structure(c(-0.121, -0.1205, -0.1225, -0.149, -0.485, -0.49, 
   -0.295, -0.295, -0.295, -0.56, -0.1575, -0.56, -0.69, -0.67, 
   -0.117, -0.08, -0.1095, -0.1095), .Dim = c(3L, 6L))

ids <- seq(1,6)    
M.1.sum <- colSums(M)
M.2.sum <- colSums(M2)

# http://stackoverflow.com/q/22305023/54964
means.long <- melt(M.1.sum, M.2.sum)
ggplot(means.long, aes(x=ids, y=value ))+ # ,fill=factor(ids))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar",position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name="ECG",
                      breaks=c(1, 2),
                      labels=c("1", "2"))+
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=min,fun.ymax=max,geom="errorbar",
               color="grey80",position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  xlab("ID")+ylab("Sum potential")

#deprecated because stat_summary designed for the case
#barplot(M.1.sum, ids)
#barplot(M.2.sum, ids)
```

Output does not look right

[image]

Expected output: 6x two columns side by side with legend of two items

Not sure how to use this one `fill=factor(ids)))` because I did not label any columns in the table. 
How can you better make the table?

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Please get into the habit of sharing your data - or a sample of your data -  reproducibly with `dput()`. It is copy/pasteable and will duplicate the data structure.

Comment: Tbh, the `sprintf("sum(sum)")` lines are not very helpful. Clearer if you just show the command and the output as it appears in the console. To minimize the data, try `dput(head(M, 20))` or similar. More advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/

Comment: Also, what is the point of lines like `sprintf("M")`? Surely this just prints the letter "M". What is the relevance?

Comment: `dput(my_data[1:20, 1:6])` will give the first 20 rows and a six columns of your data. Just provide whatever sample of your data is sufficient to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Also, please clarify your expected output. We can now nicely see `M` is a matrix with a bunch of rows and 6 columns. `sum(M)` will sum all the values of `M`. You say you expect a 6x6 matrix out. What defines the rows in your desired output? Are you just looking for `rowSums(M)` (which would be nrow x 1) or `colSums(M)` (which would be 6 x 1)?

Comment: M is great now. Still confused about your inclusion of `sprintf` and your desired result.

Comment: Fyi, "desired output" means the expected values corresponding to the example input, not just a description of their dimensions. Anyway, sounds like you just needed the colSums function.

Comment: Please stop editing your question, "moving the goalposts" as it were. If your original example didn't capture the complexity of your data and you are unable to generalize the answer to your data, open a new question with a better example.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the number of rows. It's the `id`s that you changed. In your example you just use `1:6`, then you changed them to some vector you pulled out of nowhere. If you use my exact code (with `col = 1:ncol(M)`) you should get a plot just fine. Perhaps then you can just label it differently? `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c(1, 777, 2, 4, 5, 6))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ggplot`, it is essential to have a single data frame with everything in it (at least for a single plotting layer, e.g., all the bars in a plot). You create a data frame of the column sums, and then try to use external vectors for the id and the grouping, which makes things difficult.

This is how I would do it:

```
means = rbind(
    data.frame(mean = colSums(M), source = "M", col = 1:ncol(M)),
    data.frame(mean = colSums(M2), source = "M2", col = 1:ncol(M2))
)

means$col = factor(means$col)
## one nice data frame with everything needed for the plot    
means
#       mean source col
# 1  -0.6400      M   1
# 2  -1.4650      M   2
# 3  -0.8850      M   3
# 4  -1.6950      M   4
# 5  -2.0300      M   5
# 6  -0.2700      M   6
# 7  -0.3640     M2   1
# 8  -1.1240     M2   2
# 9  -0.8850     M2   3
# 10 -1.2775     M2   4
# 11 -1.4770     M2   5
# 12 -0.2990     M2   6

ggplot(means, aes(x = col, y = mean, fill = source)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

You seem to want error bars too. I have no idea what would define those error bars - if you look at `geom_errorbar` it expects aesthetics `ymin` and `ymax`. If you calculate whatever values you want and add them as column to the data frame above, adding the error bar to the plot should be easy.

Comment: Please, see the body for my attempt to integrate errorbars here. I think you can do R2 errors by `sd`. I am not sure about the data structure which I can use in `y.sd`. What do you think?

Comment: Please let this question be done - it has been modified lots already and has now been answered. If you have new issues, open a new question.

Comment: Not to mention this answer is **very specific** about appropriate data structure for plotting error bars with `ggplot2`: *take the `means` data frame in this answer and add two columns. One for the `ymin` of the error bar and one for the `ymax` of the error bar.*

Comment: Lastly, I think using SD as an error bar for the sum is a very bad idea. A standard deviation is a common choice for error bar for a *mean*. You are not doing a mean, rather a sum, which is mean * n. When SD is commonly used for mean, to use them instead for mean * n seems misleading. If you don't know what type of error bars are appropriate, that is not a programming question and you should ask on stats.stackexchange instead. *How to add error bars to a plot* is on-topic here, *What error bars should I use* is on-topic at stats.stackexchange.