# GGplot scale_fill_discrete not creating a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the code in a prior stackoverflow post, which previously made me the graph i wanted, with a legend, however now i am using the exact same code yet i am not getting a legend on my barplot.

```
dput(year.dat2)
structure(list(year = structure(c(1136044800, 1167577200, 1199113200, 
1230735600, 1262275200, 1136044800, 1167577200, 1199113200, 1230735600, 
1262275200, 1136044800, 1167577200, 1199113200, 1230735600, 1262275200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("SM1", 
"SM2", "SM3"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.24863586758821, 
1.23185757914453, 1.10997352162401, 1.13683917747257, 0.987520605867152, 
2.21498726809749, 1.6378992693761, 1.25635623380691, 1.13585705516765, 
1.10169569342842, 7.40955802109858, 5.7940698875978, 6.03438772314438, 
6.82271157830123, 7.24402375195127)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = 
c("year", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(year.dat2, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "variable",
                      breaks = c(1, 2, 3),
                      labels = c("SM1", "SM2", "SM3")) +
  xlab("year") + 
  ylab("yearly Sub Mean")
```

Resulting plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: In this instance, it is not really necessary to clutter your question with the data cleaning step as no error occurs there.  Instead, the issue arises with plotting of the data `year.dat2`.  I think you can delete all the `cleanData` steps and instead paste the output of `dput(year.dat2)` as that is what we need directly to reproduce the problem.

Comment: edited post as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `breaks` in `scale_fill_discrete`, they do not correspond to values of your factored `variable` data used as fill `aes`.

This is the code you want:

```
ggplot(year.dat2, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "variable",
                  labels = c("SM1", "SM2", "SM3")) +
  xlab("year") + 
  ylab("yearly Sub Mean")
```

Note 1: You do not even need the `labels` parameter as you are not renaming the `variable` categories. `scale_fill_discrete(name = "variable")` would be sufficient or `labs(fill="variable")` is all you need to change the legend title.

Note 2: In your original post you linked to this SO question: [How to get a barplot with several variables side by side grouped by a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305023/how-to-get-a-barplot-with-several-variables-side-by-side-grouped-by-a-factor)

Here, the `breaks` in the sample code `scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender", breaks=c(1, 2), labels=c("Male", "Female"))` actually references the values of `gender` in the original df. Meanwhile, `labels` was used to rename `1` to `Male` and `2` to `Female` in the legend.

```
  Group.1      tea     coke     beer    water gender
1       1 87.70171 27.24834 24.27099 37.24007      1
2       2 24.73330 25.27344 25.64657 24.34669      2
```

On the other hand, there are no `1,2,3` values in your `variable` data that would match the `breaks` you have set in your original code, and that is why your legend is not plotted.

And for fun, here is an example how you might use `breaks` and `labels` in your data set:

```
ggplot(year.dat2, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "variable",
                  breaks = c("SM2", "SM3", "SM1"),
                  labels = c("SM2 new label", "SM3 new label", "SM1 new label")) +
  xlab("year") + 
  ylab("yearly Sub Mean")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was driving me insane today haha.

Comment: @TimHowat if the answer solves your problem please accept the answer to mark this answered.