# Grouped bar chart in R with 4 bars for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

So basically I am trying to figure out how to make a bar chart look like this in ggplot2 - and failing...

[image]

and this is my data

```
DF <- structure(list(Location = c("PC_of_recapped_cells", "PC_of_infested_cells", 
"PC_Recapped_and_Infested", "PC_Normal_mites"), S1 = c(7.31, 
3.2, 85.71, 85.71), S2 = c(7.46, 2.63, 83.33, 100), S3 = c(12.17, 
11.3, 30.77, 69.23), S4 = c(10.77, 5.72, 82.35, 76.47), C1 = c(6.59, 
0, 0, 0), C2 = c(15.94, 0, 0, 0), TS3 = c(14.97, 16.77, 25, 39.29
)), .Names = c("Location", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "C1", "C2", 
"TS3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

"Error: `col_names` must be TRUE, FALSE or a character vector"

Comment: Hi Natasha, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you've tried so far. That way it's easier to identify what you were doing wrong.

Comment: My guess is you will need to "reshape" your dataset.  See the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212106/creating-grouped-bar-plot-of-multi-column-data-in-r)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305023/how-to-get-a-barplot-with-several-variables-side-by-side-grouped-by-a-factor)

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); DF %>% gather(key, value, -Location) %>% ggplot(aes(x = key, y = value, fill = Location)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")`

Comment: Hiya, I have been trying to follow what Markus posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot) but as I have four bars for each of the 7 items, I am getting very confused!!

I have also tried to reshape my data as aosmith suggested but, nothing seems to be happening - I think I am just getting very confused as I have more than two bars in each item!

Comment: It should work exactly the same as in that example: If there were 4 different levels in `factor(Reason)` instead of 2, there would be 4 bars in each group. If you're still having trouble, edit your question with your best attempt to use the method shown in that linked question. Then we can help figure out what the problem is, or why your case differs from that question

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I have done it now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do some manual cleanup in your text file by changing the spaces to commas:

```
Location,S1,S2,S3,S4,C1,C2,TS3
PC_of_recapped_cells,7.31,7.46,12.17,10.77,6.59,15.94,14.97
PC_of_infested_cells,3.20,2.63,11.30,5.72,0.00,0.00,16.77
PC_Recapped_and_Infested,85.71,83.33,30.77,82.35,0.00,0.00,25.00
PC_Normal_mites,85.71,100.00,69.23,76.47,0.00,0.00,39.29
```

Then you can load in the data using the tidyverse read_csv() function and reshape it as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  file_path %>% 
  read_csv() %>% 
  gather(key = type, value = pct, -Location) %>% 
  mutate(type = fct_relevel(type, c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "C1", "C2", "TS3")))

df
   Location                 type     pct
   <chr>                    <chr>  <dbl>
 1 PC_of_recapped_cells     S1      7.31
 2 PC_of_infested_cells     S1      3.2 
 3 PC_Recapped_and_Infested S1     85.7 
 4 PC_Normal_mites          S1     85.7 
 5 PC_of_recapped_cells     S2      7.46
 6 PC_of_infested_cells     S2      2.63
...
```

Then it can be plotted:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = pct, fill = Location)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

You should be able to take it from there when it comes to recoloring, renaming labels and other changes.

Comment: I'm still getting errors? Sorry to be so confused by this!

[link to photo of whats happening] https://imgur.com/0TJREqq

Comment: You made a typo

Comment: @Hugh - ooops, thanks! 
Now I get "Error: `col_names` must be TRUE, FALSE or a character vector" - do you have any ideas? I am really struggling with the whole thing!